# Работа с AsyncTask

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, никогда раньше не сталкивался с AsyncTask и вот подошло время. Мне нужно, в AsyncTask засунуть определение местоположения. Я делаю так:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Geolocation();
}
private void Geolocation() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
        private Exception m_error = null;@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Search ...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

            progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected void doInBackground() {

            //-------------------------Местоположение---------------------------//
            LocationManager locationManager;
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            updateWithNewLocation(location);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,
            locationListener);

        }

        // обновляем progressDialog
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressDialog.setProgress((int)((values[0] / (float) values[1]) * 100));
        };

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // отображаем сообщение, если возникла ошибка
            if (m_error != null) {
                m_error.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            // закрываем прогресс и удаляем временный файл
            progressDialog.hide();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    };
}
```

Но почему-то не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Хотя если убрать AsyncTask и вставить код между комментариями "местоположение" в OnCreate, то все будет работать, но мне нужно, чтобы оно работало в AsyncTask.

ОБНОВЛЕНО:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                         setContentView(R.layout.main);
                           LocationManager locationManager;
                           String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
                        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                 criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                 criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                 criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                   criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
               String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                  updateWithNewLocation(location);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);
                  }

       private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {//постоянное обновление.
         updateWithNewLocation(location);
           }

      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
          updateWithNewLocation(null);
            }

       public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){                          }
           };

           @SuppressLint("NewApi")
             private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
              String latLongString;
            TextView myLocationText;
           myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);

           String addressString = "No address found";

               if (location != null) {                              
             double latitude = location.getLatitude();
             double longitude = location.getLongitude();
             Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
               List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);

        if (address.getCountryName() != null) {
            country_location = address.getCountryName(); 
        }
        if (address.getLocality() != null) {
            city_location = address.getLocality(); 
        } 
        if (address.getThoroughfare() != null) {
            street_location = address.getThoroughfare(); 
        }
        if (address.getFeatureName() != null) {
            house_location = address.getFeatureName(); 
        }

        geolocation.append(country_location).append(",");
        geolocation.append(city_location).append(",");
        geolocation.append(street_location).append(",");
        geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");

    }
        addressString = geolocation.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {}
    } else {
  latLongString = "No location found";
   updateWithNewLocation(location);
       }
    myLocationText.setText(addressString);
   }
```

ОБНОВЛЕНО 2:

```
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.create_consumption);
                     //-------------------------Местоположение---------------------------//
              LocationManager locationManager;
                String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
                locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

             // Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            Location location;
               // updateWithNewLocation(location);

             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,
                                                   locationListener);
              //-------------------------Местоположение---------------------------//
             mt = new MyTask();
                mt.execute();
             }
                     private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              //  updateWithNewLocation(location);
                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
                  updateWithNewLocation(null);
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                            Bundle extras){ }
              };

              @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
          String latLongString;
        TextView myLocationText;
       myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);

       String addressString = "No address found";

           if (location != null) {                              
         double latitude = location.getLatitude();
         double longitude = location.getLongitude();
         Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
           List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);

    if (address.getCountryName() != null) {
        country_location = address.getCountryName(); 
    }
    if (address.getLocality() != null) {
        city_location = address.getLocality(); 
    } 
    if (address.getThoroughfare() != null) {
        street_location = address.getThoroughfare(); 
    }
    if (address.getFeatureName() != null) {
        house_location = address.getFeatureName(); 
    }

    geolocation.append(country_location).append(",");
    geolocation.append(city_location).append(",");
    geolocation.append(street_location).append(",");
    geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");

}
    addressString = geolocation.toString();
  } catch (IOException e) {}
   } else {
 latLongString = "No location found";
   updateWithNewLocation(location);
   }
  myLocationText.setText(addressString);
 }

              class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                      super.onPreExecute();

                    }

                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        updateWithNewLocation(location);

                   return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                      super.onPostExecute(result);

                    }
                  }
```

ОБНОВЛЕНО :

```
             private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        String latLongString;
        myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);
        String addressString = "No address found";
            if (location != null) {
                   double latitude = location.getLatitude();
               double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                mt = new MyTask();
                mt.execute(latitude,longitude);
               }
              }

          class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
                        }

      protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {                                                      
             String addressString = "No address found";
     Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
     try {
      List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
              Address address = addresses.get(0);
              if (address.getCountryName() != null) {
                  country_location = address.getCountryName(); 
                  geolocation.append(country_location).append(",");
                      }
              if (address.getLocality() != null) {
                  city_location = address.getLocality(); 
                  geolocation.append(city_location).append(",");
                      } 
              if (address.getThoroughfare() != null) {
                  street_location = address.getThoroughfare(); 
                  geolocation.append(street_location).append(",");
                      }
              if (address.getFeatureName() != null) {
                  house_location = address.getFeatureName(); 
                  geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");
                      }

              addressString = geolocation.toString();

                      }
                     return addressString;
                  }
                }
            protected void onPostExecute(String addressString) {
                myLocationText.setText(addressString);
                        }
              }
```

Comment: Эммм, сделайте нормальное форматирование кода. Иначе ничего не понять. И кроме того, AsyncTask созданный нужно еще и вызывать: new MyTask().execute(params). В коде не увидел подобного. Вообще - определение местоположения выносить в таск - сомнительная затея.

Comment: Сделал форматирование, определение местоположения я вынес в таск, так как если его не вынести, то Activity будет долго открываться ( т.е. пока не будет выполнено нахождение местоположения), а так Активити откроется и пользователь может что-то делать, а местоположение будет параллельно определяться.

Comment: AsyncTask предназначен для выполнения задач в фоне. В вашем же случае я что-то не вижу эксэкюта таска.

Comment: Обновил код: теперь открывается Activity и виснет. Это может быть связано с тем, что вызов  updateWithNewLocation(location);  и LocationListener находятся вне класса AsyncTask ? и как сделать правильно?

Comment: Получение координат и так асинхронное, зачем вам AsyncTask? Ловите свои координаты в locationListener'е и все.

Comment: В данный момент у меня код, который написан в ОБНОВЛЕНО без всяких AsyncTask. Он работает, но он меня не устраивает тем, что при переходе на эту Activity, у меня идет задержка, т.е. идет определение местоположения и пока он не закончит выполняться - Activity не откроется. А мне нужно как то сделать, чтобы открылось Activity и уже в ходе работы с этим Activity параллельно определялось местоположение. Вот я и спрашиваю, так как первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой. Само местоположение записывается в myLocationText. Пример того, что я хочу получить - это приложение Google+. Помогите,пожалуйст

Comment: Посмотрите [профайлером](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) на чем у вас идет торможение. ИМХО, в getLastKnownLocation необходимости нету (хотя по идее оно не должно быть блокирующим). И если и надо использовать AsyncTask, то только для этого вызова...

Comment: закомментил везде вызов функции updateWithNewLocation(location); и все открывается нормально - без задержек. Значит торможение происходит из-за этой функции.Как можно изменить ?

Comment: А, ну там же у вас еще и геокодер используется. Вот его как раз и надо в AsyncTask пихать.

[Geocoder][1].getFromLocation:

> The returned values may be obtained by means of a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

[1]:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Serjuk](/users/8570/serjuk), Немного не так. В функции updateWithNewLocation вам нужно стартовать AsyncTask для GeoCoder'а, т.е. весь код, который относится к запросу в сеть и его постобработка должен быть в другом потоке.

1. Получили координаты в locationListener'е
2. Запускаете updateWithNewLocation, получаете широту и долготу.
3. Доходите до обращения к геокодеру, запускаете ваш `AsyncTask<Double, Void, String>` (первый параметр - массив Double ширина и долгота, второй параметр - это прогресс, не нужен, третий параметр - результат, строка которую вернул геокодер), передав туда широту и долготу.
4. В doInBackground делаете запрос к геокодеру, возвращаете строку с ответом геокодера.
5. В onPostExecute вы уже находитесь в главном потоке, где можно менять интерфейс и у вас есть ответ геокодера.

Поищите примеры работы с AsyncTask, ничего сложного нет. Просто надо понимать в какой момент где вы находитесь (в каком потоке). И про профайлер посмотрите - оч полезная штука хоть и тормозит безбожно...

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста последнее обновление. Попробовал по примеру сделать. я так понимаю, что в execute я передаю mt.execute(latitude,longitude); а потом в doInBackground возвращаю строку addressString и печатаю ее в  onPostExecute. Но почему то у меня ругается на строчки  Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); и на } после    return addressString;

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    doInBackground(Double... params){
      double latitude = params[0];
      double longitude = params[1];
      Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(YourActivityClass.this, Locale.getDefault());
      List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
      ...

Синтаксические ошибки тут сложно увидеть, разметка съехала, проверйте скобки лишние/не хватает...

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько замечаний.

1) Нельзя "долгоживущие" инициализации выводить в конструктор. Есть понятие [Lazy Initiliazation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) - в Android'е это самое оно

2) `AsyncTask` это по сути отдельный тред (нить) выполнения. Ее надо сначала декларировать, а потом отдельно запускать. В данном случае надо сделать так:

- Сделать в конструкторе Lazy Init (инициализация членов класса которые не требуют ресурсов/времени)
- Задекларировать `AsyncTask` (у вас он задекларирован, но анонимно).
- Далее запустить ваш `AsyncTask` (наверное где-то в `onCreate()`)

И еще совет, старайтесь вначале избегать анонимных деклараций классов/методов. Это здорово затуманивает понимание. Потом когда нахватаетесь будете использовать анонимные классы/методы.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, Посмотрите правильно ли я понял ? т.е. нужно всю функцию updateWithNewLocation(location); в AsyncTask пихнуть ? Eclipse ругается в protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
на строчку updateWithNewLocation(location);